# How do I get a watermark on a sigplus gallery?

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, joomla-3.7

I have install SigPlus 1.5.0.262 on Joomla! 3.7.5. I am just trying to get the watermark to work. I cannot seem to get it to appear. I *think* my issue is just where I am placing my image. According to the [advanced guide](https://hunyadi.info.hu/sigplus/sigplus-advanced-usage)..

> A watermark is a PNG file with transparency channel (i.e. the image has RGBA color scheme) placed either **in the same folder** where the images to be shown are (specified within the plug-in activation start and end tags), or in the **image base folder** (specified in the administration back-end).

I interpret the "base folder" as /images.

I have tried both of those locations and I still cannot get it to show up. Its simple small png.

Under the advanced settings for the module I have changed the settings for watermark

[image: Advanced watermark settings]

Things beyond above I tried:

- Using a bad file name on purpose. Does **not** trigger an error state that I could find.
- Nothing in any logs I could find e.g. administrator\logs\error.php

Comment: If you are using relative paths, which other paths have you tried? Normally, when a program tries to access an image that doesn't exist in the directory where it is told to look, a clue is provided in the form of an error.  I've not yet used SigPlus, but I would hope that there would be some feedback in the form of server-side or client-side errors.  Please try to discover some new details to share with us.

Comment: I have not tried any paths but tried puttinh the image into the locations i think it expects it. There are not any errors to be seen. Perhaps it is finding it but it does not like the image itself. I will see what i can turn up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>I thought I had already done this before I posted but I tried again and got positive results</sup>

So after looking at a [post about a supposed bug with an earlier version of the plugin](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=589500) there was a couple of clues as to a solution from the developer

> The module, however, *does not have an image base folder*, which means that the only place you could put *watermark.png* in the current implementation of the sigplus module is the *image gallery folder*.

and

> you should create a subfolder *watermark* inside the image gallery folder, and place *watermark.png* within that subfolder.

I created a folder called watermark in the root of the gallery folder (identified as **image source** in the module properties) and placed the watermark.png inside that folder.

Changed the **Advanced Settings** > **Filename for watermark** to "watermark/watermark.png"

After changes were saved and associated page refreshed I was able to see the watermark.

Comment: Great self-solve.  Thanks for posting a clear, informative answer for future researchers.

Comment: Well done for figuring it out and providing lots of info in both your question and answer